# Lower bound on smallest eigenvalue of (symmetric positive-definite) matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

If $M$ is a symmetric positive-definite matrix, is it possible to get a **positive** lower bound on the smallest eigenvalue of $M$ in terms of a matrix norm of $M$ or elements of $M$? E.g., I want $$\lambda_{\text{min}} \geq f(\lVert M \rVert)$$ or something like that. $M$ is a Gram matrix, if that helps.

Comment: Hi @ampeo, have you found the answer? I have the same question and all the bounds I can get are negative, which doesn't make any sense for a PD matrix.

Comment: There is an obvious bound in terms of the operator norm of $M^{-1}$, of course.

Comment: As user7530 wrote, $\lambda_{min}$ depends essentially on $M^{-1}$. Moreover to find an inequality in the form $\lambda_{min}\geq f(||M||)$ is beyond all hope. For instance let $A_{\epsilon}=diag(1,\epsilon)$. We should obtain, for every $\epsilon >0$, $\epsilon\geq f(1)$ (for $||.||_2$).

Comment: Lower bounds on the smallest eigenvalue of a positive definite matrix are related to estimates of the condition number, for which see [my Answer to a SciComp.SE Question](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/6806/651).

Answer (score 8):

There is one lower bound on minimum eigenvalue of symmetric p.d. matrix given in [Applied Math. Sc., vol. 4, no. 64] which is based on Frobenius norm (F) and Euclidean norm (E)

$$ \lambda_{min} \gt \sqrt{\frac{||A||_F^2-n||A||_E^2}{n(1-||A||_E^2/|det(A)|^{2/n})}} $$

if it helps.

[reference]: K. H. Schindler, "A New Lower Bound for the Minimal Singular Value for Real Non-Singular Matrices by a Matrix Norm and Determinant", Journal of Applied Mathematical Sciences, Vol. 4, No. 64, 2010.

Comment: Rather than reposting (with the same "typos" as best I can tell), you could have edited this, your original post.  See "edit" link just under the Answer.  I took a guess at the mismatched parenthesis in the denominator; please check it is correct.

Comment: It is all correct, Thanks!

Comment: @Saeed Thanks for this! Is there a chance you could find the article on Google Scholar and post a link? I can't find it anywhere (not sure if Sc. is short for something...)

Comment: @Elements http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2010/ams-61-64-2010/schindlerAMS61-64-2010-1.pdf

Comment: @Elements you can also search the title in google scholar: "A New Lower Bound for the Minimal Singular Value for Real Non-Singular Matrices
by a Matrix Norm and Determinant" Applied mathematical Sciences Vol. 4, No. 64

Comment: @SaeedManaffam The Schindler's bound (even as stated in the published paper) is wrong. You can have a look at the proof and realize the elementary mistakes the author has made. Also, see my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737340/lower-bound-on-the-smallest-eigenvalue/1330651#1330651

Comment: `n=3` `H = {{3, -3, 11}, {-3, 11, -27}, {11, -27, 83}}` `Min[Eigenvalues[H]] >= Sqrt[(Norm[H]^2 - n Norm[H]^2)/(n (1 - Norm[H]^2/Abs[Det[H]]^(2/n)))] // N`

If I'm not mistaken anywhere, then your method does not work for the proposed matrix.

Answer (score 5):

A quick comment: If you have diagonal dominance, then [Gerhsgorin's circle theorem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem&ei=pKUiUun7DJXQsATfnIDoBQ&usg=AFQjCNFgcxCvB-_iFubVENtxtz_JF025iw&sig2=tAldUCkYk-KQU2Fn9M8TwA&bvm=bv.51495398,d.cWc%22Gershgorin%20Circle%20Theorem%22) for eigenvalues will get you at least something. So for each row, subtract the diagonal term from the sum of the absolute values of the off-diagonal terms, and take the minimum over the rows. That is a bound on the eigenvalue that will be positive (again, if you have diagonal dominance, which may not hold for all Gram matrices).