# Find the uniform lower bound of the smallest eigenvalue of a certain matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, upper-lower-bounds

I am handling a problem of finding a unifom lower bound ( away from zero ) of  the smallest eigenvalue of  the following real symmetric matrix

$$A =\begin{pmatrix} n & n-1 & n-2 & \cdots & 1\\
n-1 & n-1 & n-2 & \cdots & 1 \\
n-2 & n-2 & n-2 & \cdots & 1 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I did some simulation (simulate n from 2 to 1500 ), it shows that the smallest eigenvalue of this matrix may have a lower bound around 0.25. So I try to prove it.

First, I found there may have some results related to the problem. Such as 
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1330651

So I try to use

$$ \lambda_{min} \gt \sqrt{\frac{||A||_F^2-n||A||_E^2}{n(1-||A||_E^2/|det(A)|^{2/n})}} $$

**or** the result ( Theorem 1 ) in [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242985986_Bounds_for_eigenvalues_using_the_trace_and_determinant). But only get a trivial lower bound **zero**.

Then I try to use [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) to solve the following equivalent problem

$$\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n,~\|x\|_2 = 1} x^{\top} A x$$

By some calculate, I think this problem is the following optimization

$$
\min_{x_i \in \mathbb{R}} x_1^2 + (x_1+x_2)^2 + \cdots (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2~~s.t. ~~\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = 1
$$

or at least find a lower bound of the object function. I tried the method of Lagrange multipliers, and the trigonometric functions to reformular the problem. But I got stuck because of the complicated calculation.

So, I wonder is there anyone may have some ideas about the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is correct. The inverse of $A$ is a symmetric tridiagonal matrix:
$$
A^{-1}=\pmatrix{
1&-1\\
-1&2&-1\\
&-1&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&-1\\
&&&-1&2}
$$
[whose eigenvalues are known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1857078) to be $\mu_j=4\sin^2\left(\frac{j-\frac12}{n+\frac12}\frac\pi2\right)$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$. So, the minimum eigenvalue of $A$ is $\dfrac1{\mu_n}=\left[4\sin^2\left(\frac{n-\frac12}{n+\frac12}\frac\pi2\right)\right]^{-1}$, which approaches $\frac14$ from the right when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! The reference is really great!