# Comparing different norms of a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, optimization

For $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a=(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{m}) \in \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$, consider the polynomial $P_{a}$ defined by
$$
P_{a} (x):= a_0 + a_1 x^2 + \ldots + a_{m}x^{2m}\text{, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.}
$$
Then there is $C_m >0$ such that for every $a \in \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$, we have
$$
\int_{[0,1]} P_{a}(x)^2 dx \geq C_m \|a\|^2,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the standard Euclidean norm. The existence of $C_m$ is guaranteed by the following compactness argument. Define the (continuous) function $\phi : \mathbb{R}^{m+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
\phi(a) := \int_{[0,1]} P_{a}(x)^2 dx.
$$
Then for $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $\phi(ra)= r^2 \phi(a)$ and hence $\phi(a)= \|a\|^2 \phi(a/\|a\|)$. So $C_m$ can be taken to be $C_m = \min_{v \in \mathbb{S}^m} \phi(v)$.

My questions are the following:

1. Can we get a lower bound for $C_m$ (in terms of $m$)?
2. Do we know which value of $a \in \mathbb{S}^{m}$ minimizes the function $\phi$?

My guess is that the minimizer $a_{\text{min}}$ must have coordinates whose signs alternate so that it minimizes the value of $a_0 + a_1 x^2 + \ldots + a_{m}x^{2m}$, but $a_j$'s should not have the same absolute value. Rather, they should increase in some way.

Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting question. +1

Answer (score 1):

We can compute the integral for a start. Squaring the sum and integrating the monomials we find
$$ \phi(a) = \sum \limits_{k,l = 0}^m \frac{a_k a_l}{2(k+l)+1} \equiv \langle a, B_m a \rangle \, , $$
where $B_m \in \mathbb{R}^{(m+1) \times (m+1)}$ is a symmetric, positive definite matrix with entries
$$(B_m)_{kl} = [2(k+l)+1]^{-1}$$
for $0 \leq k,l \leq m$. Therefore, the optimal $C_m$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $B_m$ and the minimisers in $\mathbb{S}^m$ are the two (numerically, it seems that all eigenvalues are distinct) corresponding normalised eigenvectors. They are probably not easy to find in general.

Numerically, $C_m \simeq 10^{-3m/2}$ appears to hold. So far, I have found the lower bound
$$ C_m \geq \left(\frac{m}{\operatorname{tr} (B_m)}\right)^m \det (B_m) \, , $$
stated for example in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242985986_Bounds_for_Eigenvalues_Using_the_Trace_and_Determinant) paper (Eq. (1.4), $n = m + 1$, $k = 1$; found in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1330651/570419) answer). It is not particulary good in our case, though. Other bounds are discussed [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.00108), but they also don't seem very helpful.