# Positive eigenvalues of Gramian matrix $W = O^TO$, where $O$ is full rank.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

Consider a $m\times n$ matrix $A$ of rank $n$, where $n \leq m$. Let $W = A^TA$. I want to find a lower **positive** bound on the eigenvalues of $W$.

Because $A$ is full rank, I know that the eigenvalues of $W$ must be all positive. However, can I find a relationship with respect to the $A$? Can I say that the $\min_i\{\lambda_i(W)\}=\min_i\{\lambda_i(A)^2\}$ if $A$ is square? Where $\lambda_i(M)$ denotes the set the eigenvalues of a matrix $M$.

**Extra info**: 
For control theorists, the $A$ matrix here is the observability matrix and $W$ is the observability Gramian.

-------------------Edition------------------------------------------

I don't know if it is useful, but my $A$ matrix has special structure:
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} B \\ BC^{p_1} \\ BC^{p_2} \\ \vdots \\ BC^{p_i}  
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $B$, $C$ are of proper dimensions and $p_i>\dots>p_2>p_1>0$ are positive integers. The only special characteristic of $C$ is that it is an $n \times n$ invertible matrix. 
In that case we have that:
$$W = B^TB+C^TB^T+\dots+C^{pT}B^TBC^p$$
Then, $\lambda_{min}(W) \geq \lambda_{min}(B^TB)+\lambda_{min}(C^TB^T)+\dots+\lambda_{min}(C^{pT}B^TBC^p)$ because all matrices in the summation are symmetric. 
But this bound doesn't help me much because it may easily ended up being zero, even though I know there is a higher bound.

Comment: If $A$ is not square, then it cannot have eigenvalues. I don't know if this helps, but the eigenvalues of $W$ are the squares of the singular values of $A$.

Comment: $B$ is also $n$ by $n?$ Seems it must be.

Comment: Sorry, you are right $A$ if I talked about eigenvalues should be square. $B$ however, doesn't neet to be.

Comment: Here's a more general answer for positive definite matrices: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480504/lower-bound-on-smallest-eigenvalue-of-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix